# doctrine:migrations:migrate : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to migrate my database in production (MySQL 5.6) with command: `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

I put this in Doctrine.yalm:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.6'
```

I don't know why I have error messages:

> Migration 20200426103129 failed during Execution. Error An exception
>   occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT
>   NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password
>   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email),
>   PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE
>   utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL,
>   password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C7' at
>   line 1 13:03:10 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command
>   "doctrine:migrations:migrate". Message: "An exception occurred while
>   executing 'CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email
>   VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT
>   NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id))
>   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE =
>   InnoDB':\n\nSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX
>   UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C7' at line 1" ["exception" =>
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException^ { …},"command" =>
>   "doctrine:migrations:migrate","message" => """  An exception occurred
>   while executing 'CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
>   email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password
>   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email),
>   PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE
>   utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':\n  \n  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT
>   NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C7' at line 1  """]
>
> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 79:
>                                                                                                                                                An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE user (id INT
>   AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT
>   NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX
>   UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET
>   utf8mb4 COLLA     TE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                                          SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> ```
>
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you
>   r MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT
>   NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E792
>   7C7' at line 1

In PDOConnection.php line 90:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you
  r MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E792
  7C7' at line 1

In PDOConnection.php line 88:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you
  r MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E792
  7C7' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by myself.
There is lot of tread related with this issue but always partial answers are given.

For other people having this issue here is the full explanation:

When creating User entity with Symfony you will have a JSON column to manage roles.
Is your SQL version is under 5.7.8 you MUST indicate the version in doctrine.yaml file like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.6'
```

It is not all: if you had error message SQLSTATE[42000] when trying to migrate your database you MUST as well remove files generated in src/migration folder.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON column type is not available until MySQL 5.7.8, so you cannot add such a column to your database

Comment: JSON type has been applied automatically by Symfony to role field in User entity. What should I do to change the column type without breaking anything ?

Comment: According to this documentation [https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-security/user-entity]  I should not have this issue if I fulfill `server_version: '5.6'` in Doctrine.yalm